# Three column conditions in database

Tags: mysql, database, npgsql

Is it possible to get 3 column names as conditions in database?

ex:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1=value1, column2=value2, column3=value3
```

Comment: use `and` instead of a comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with and clause

```
 SELECT * FROM table 
 WHERE column1=value1
 and  column2=value2
 and  column3=value3;
```